# How to deploy REST web service to Heroku?

Tags: java, rest, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple java rest service using webapp-runner in heroku, i follow the instructions in documentation and everything perfect, i run my app and is working cause i can see my html welcom page, the problem is that i cant access to my rest resources with the path i provided even in a local deploy http://localhost:8282 this is the path when i open my app, http://localhost:8282/wr/test and this should show a simple get method, but doesn't work neither local with webapp-runner nor remote in heroku, this is the link https://appbergas.herokuapp.com/ , what am i doing wrong? which should be the complete uri i thought https://appbergas.herokuapp.com/wr/test
im using javax ws rs,also when i deploy it in glassfish everything goes great.